# Schedule query failure in GCP with 'The caller does not have permission' error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I created a python script similar to [BQ tutorial on SQ][1].  The service account has been set using os.environ.  When executing with BigQuery Admin and other similar permissions(Data user, Data transfer agent, Data view etc) the schedule query creation fails with

```
 status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "The caller does not have permission"
```

The least permission level it is accepting is 'Project Owner'.  As this is a service account, I was hoping a lower permission level can be applied eg Bigquery Admin, as all I need with the Service account is to remotely create schedule queries.  Even the how to guide says it should work.  Can anyone provide some input if there is any other combination of permissions which will allow this to work please.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries

Comment: Can you please share your scheduled query? It is possible that you need additional permission depending on what your query does.

Comment: @AnjelaB its the same code as on the google site for scheule query setup(the actual query is a select * from a table without any restrictions or row level security applied), the permissions were as per the page, bigquery admin, additionally i gave the others, the SA only works when project level owner\editor permission is given.

Comment: Given your scenario that you have already met the minimum required [permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions), I suggest filing an [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that a support can fully check your account.